# Retrieve Function Key Name used in HTTP Hook in Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am assuming that the purpose of `Function Keys` in Azure Functions is to allow for multiple consumers of a function to each have their own unique `Function Key`. Thus, it would be easy for me to Revoke a key should we no longer want a vendor to be able to call that function.

However, I would also like to use that `Function Key` as a lookup to find which vendor called the Function. I could not find anything in the documentation on how to do this, nor is there anything in the `HttpRequestMessage` object that would indicate a place to find it.

Is there a way to retrieve the `Key Name` of the `Function Key` used to call an Azure Function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Drovani,

Your assumption about the key usage is correct.

Unfortunately, that information isn't easily exposed today, but the actual key used is passed to you with the request (depending on how the client authenticated, either in as a query string named `"code"` or a header named `"x-function-keys"`), so you can derive the consumer from that information, but I agree that is not ideal, so I've opened an issue [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/926) so we can improve this.

Thank you!